# Print E=mc² or E=mc^2, by using the right side of this equation

Tags: code-golf

Your task – if you choose to accept it – is to have your program print, literally, either one of the following:

1. `E=mc²` (if your language supports Unicode (so no HTML trickery, for instance))
2. `E=mc^2` (if your language doesn't support Unicode)

Here are the conditions:

- Your program must consist of exactly two expressions (one representing the `m`, the other the `c`, in `mc²`), which, when fed into your language's representation of the formula `mc²`, and whose result is then printed, will show one of the above results.
- Both expression may be assigned to variables before feeding them into `mc²`, but the expressions themselves are not allowed to use intermediate variables.
- Both expressions must evaluate to an absolute value larger than 1 (e.g `abs(expression) > 1`).
- You may assign the result of `mc²` to an intermediate variable, representing the `E`, before printing this `E`, but that is not necessary – you may print the result of `mc²` directly as well.
- When printing the final result, you *are* allowed to use your language's libraries to convert the possibly numeric or binary result to it's string representation.
- **Added condition**: no operator overloading in the final expression that represents `mc²`. The result *must* be the algebraic result of expression `m` times expression `c` squared.

Here's an example template, of what I'm looking for, expressed in PHP:

```
$m = /* some expression */;
$c = /* some expression */;
$E = $m * pow( $c, 2 );
print $E; // should print on of the results mentioned at the beginning of this challenge
```

To be honest, I'm not even sure this challenge is doable, but my gut says it must be possible in at least one, or even a few, languages.

Winning solution is the one with the shortest code, in characters, in a week from now.

For clarification, it's perfectly fine to merely do something like this as well — if your language allows for it:

```
print( someExpression * someOtherExpression ** 2 ); // or something to that effect
```

... in other words: without assigning anything to any intermediate variables. Just as long as the algebraic calculation remains intact.

Comment: This seems like it would be extremely easy to do with operator overloading

Comment: @Hannesh Hmm, yeah, I think I'll disallow operator overloading; at least in the final expression representing `mc²` (if it's even at all possible to be that selective with operator overloading).

Comment: Any restrictions in the usage of trailing whitespaces or zero-space unicode characters?

Comment: @ThomasW. Yes: no (trailing) whitespace and/or zero-space unicode chars in the output (unless, for instance, a trailing newline is absolutely required by your language).

Comment: Point of clarification. Your example assigns the expressions to variables as do many of the solutions, but bullet point 2 says "Both expression may be assigned to variables". Does that mean we can just do E=m-expression*c-expression^2 without any other variable assignments? I can save a fair number of bytes if so. e.g. E=3*8631826306^2 ?

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre Yes, you are allowed to do that.

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre You are even allowed to do `print(3*8631826306^2)`, or something similar (without assigning to an intermediate `E` variable), if that works. Just as long as both "m" and "c" expressions evaluate to an absolute value larger than 1.

Comment: Haha, the joke is that in T-SQL ^ is a bitwise XOR. To do an exponent you have to do POWER(root, exponent). But one of these days I am going to do a crazy bit-math solution in SQL, just for fun.

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre Yeah, that's unfortunate; pretty much the same with PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## APL, 27

```
⎕UCS(2÷⍨⎕UCS'E=mc²')×(√2)*2
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
m←(⎕UCS 'E=mc²')÷2
c←√2
⎕UCS m×c*2
```

Start with the desired output string, convert it into an array of Unicode values, divide each number by 2, and assign the vector to **m**. Then assign √2 to **c**. Compute the formula and convert the resulting array back to a string. I can't tell whether the last operation is allowed by the rules, but it's akin to what most other solutions are doing, whether explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: The ungolfed version does not seems to be less golfed than the golfed one to me.

Comment: @Victor it gives names to things (m, c) and it doesn't cram everything in a single line. Other than that, no, there's not much to ungolf here.

Answer (score 15):

## C, <s>66</s> <s>59</s> 57 bytes

Ignore the compiler warnings. It should work OK as long as you compile it on a <s>big</s> *little*-endian machine. This code could probably be made a lot shorter on a 64-bit machine, but I'm unable to test:

```
main(){long long m=1130224008533LL,c=7,E=m*c*c;puts(&E);}
```

<sub>9 fewer characters thanks to [@Adam Davis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1686) and [@Michael](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16120) :-)</sub>

Comment: This even works on Ideone: http://ideone.com/SCqKFm

Comment: So far, your solution meets the requirements most strictly. As far as I can tell it ticks all the boxes.

Comment: You can save some space by using `0x1072699BD55` in place of `1130224008533LL`.

Comment: Also you can probably use `puts(` to replace `printf("%s",`

Comment: @AdamDavis Ah, I always forget about `puts()`. Thanks for pointing that out. Writing the number in hex doesn't help unfortunately — the `0x` and `LL` are both required.

Comment: @AdamDavis No, it's definitely null terminated. `E=mc^2` is only 6 characters, so it's followed by two zero bytes.

Comment: Ah, right!  I'm reading the string backwards, of course.

Comment: Why is the `LL` required? `long long m=1130224008533LL` and `long long m=1130224008533` are supposed to set `m` to the exact same value, and on my system, that does indeed work.

Comment: On 64 bit, you can use `long` instead of `long long`.

Comment: On big-endian, I think `m=76130130550322LL,c=256` or `m=2165479268986938LL,c=48` work. (I prefer the 2nd one)

Comment: Also, why don't you assign the value directly in `E` ? `long long m=1130224008533LL,c=7,E=m*c*c;`

Comment: Are you not allowed to do this directly: `puts(m*c*c);`, without using the intermediate `E` variable? Or perhaps even something like `puts((long long m=1130224008533LL)*7*7)`? (Forgive me my ignorance of C — just spitballing)

Comment: @Michael Of course! Thanks for that. @fireeyedboy Can't do that because `puts()` needs a pointer as its argument, not an integer.

Answer (score 7):

### C, <strike>57</strike> <strike>53</strike> <strike>50</strike> <strike>40</strike> 39 bytes

The rules are somewhat confusing, I do hope I read them correctly.
Works on 32bit platforms only.

```
m="E=mc^2",c=-1u/2;
main(){
    puts(m*c*c);
}
```

`c`c equals 2^31-1, so `c*c` equals 1 modulo 2^32. Therefore `m*c*c == m` (mod 2^32).
The `-1u/2` constant and `puts` are hvd's suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, but the rules stated that the expressions may not evaluate to 1 (`c=1` here).

Comment: Thanks @fireeyedboy, fixed. And shortened while I'm at it.

Comment: Is the intermediate variable `s` necessary? (Or is that a constant perhaps?) Would something like `m="E=mc^2"/4;` not be possible, for instance? (Sorry, not a C programmer.)

Comment: I get "error: initializer element is not computable at load time" with GCC 4.8.

Comment: @fireeyedboy That wouldn't work, compilers are lenient with implicit conversions between pointers and integers, but not lenient enough to allow division with a pointer operand.

Comment: Modified to 49 bytes and to compile on my system: `m="E=mc^2",c=-1u/2;main(){printf("%s\n",m*c*c);}` (Comment edited, it was 52 bytes.)

Comment: Addition to my previous comment: using `puts` instead of `printf` trims it to 40 bytes.

Comment: Thanks @hvd. Can't believe I missed `puts`.

Comment: Oops, I miscounted, sorry! Making `c` global does save a character, so what I had was actually 39 bytes, not 40: I accidentally counted one more because I included an unnecessary newline character.

Comment: @hvd I see. Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 5):

## Java: <s>261</s> <s>241</s> <s>207</s> 206 characters

Thanks to @V-X for helping me with ideas for optimizing this.

Here it is, 206 characters:

```java
import java.math.*;class N{public static void main(String[]y){BigInteger m=new BigInteger("12uy4kc5e",36),c=new BigInteger("5"),e=m.multiply(c).multiply(c);System.out.println(new String(e.toByteArray()));}}
```

Properly indented version:

```java
import java.math.*;
class N {
    public static void main(String[] y) {
        BigInteger m = new BigInteger("12uy4kc5e",36),
                   c = new BigInteger("5"),
                   e = m.multiply(c).multiply(c); // e = m * c * c
        System.out.println(new String(e.toByteArray()));
    }
}
```

Older version, Java 8 only, with 261 characters:

```java
import java.math.*;public class N{public static void main(String[]y){BigDecimal m=new BigDecimal("59324209849366147.77"),c=BigDecimal.TEN,e=m.multiply(c).multiply(c);System.out.println(new String(java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(e.toBigInteger().toByteArray())));}}
```

Ungolfed version:

```java
import java.math.*;
import static java.util.Base64.*;

public class N {
    public static void main(String[] y) {
        BigDecimal m = new BigDecimal("59324209849366147.77"),
                   c = BigDecimal.TEN,
                   e = m.multiply(c).multiply(c); // e = m * c * c

        System.out.println(new String(getDecoder().decode(e.toBigInteger().toByteArray())));
    }
}
```

Comment: Java ftw! I really enjoy all your Java answers.

Comment: Could reduce 4 bytes if I do not use an intermediate variable for e. But I prefer to use the intermediate var anyway.

Comment: by use of `m=new BigDecimal("1130224008533"),c=new BigDecimal(7),` you can get rid of 4 more characters...

Comment: @V-X I tried your suggestion and the program failed with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 5e`.

Comment: Does Java support import aliases? For instance `import java.math.BigDecimal as B`? Might help with shaving off a few extra chars.

Comment: @fireeyedboy No, java does not have this feature.

Comment: I have tried this `import java.math.*;
public class N
{
   public static void main(String a[])
   {
      BigInteger m = new BigInteger("1130224008533"),
                 c = new BigInteger("7"),
                 e = m.multiply(c).multiply(c);        
                 System.out.println(new String(e.toByteArray()));
   }
}` (215 chars after removing irrelevant spaces) but it was printing in the reversed order (I tried that in javalunch.com)

Comment: @V-X Initially I wanted to use `BigIntegers`, but unfortunately 5932420984936614777 is a squarefree number. And since java supports Unicode, it must print `E=mc²` instead of `E=mc^2`. Further, the code to reverse the `String` in your idea got too complex to be usable. But, your comment inspired me for trying to encode it differently, and I figured out that I could use a different charset, and voila: Quickly got a new shorter version by using ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Is there a reason for the specification of the charset?

Comment: @V-X This is just to make the bytes encoding `E=mc²` to form a `BigInteger` which the value has at least one squared factor, i.e, something very hackish. If I do not specify the charset, it outputs `E=mc�`.

Comment: @V-X You are right. By switching to UTF-8 encoded, I do not need to specify the encoding anymore.

Comment: I have another idea: you can transform `BigInteger m = new BigInteger("3045205223042");` into `BigInteger m = new BigInteger("12uy4kc5e",36);` which is by 1 character shorter:)

Answer (score 4):

## Perl - 32 characters

```
$m="E=mc²";$c=1.1;print$m x$c**2
```

This is sort of cheating: in Perl's `x` operator, the right operand is converted to an integer, so both 1.1 and 1.21 (1.1**2), despite having a value larger than 1, behave exactly as 1.

Comment: Haha, sneaky. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

### TI-89 basic (needs CAS) - 17

```
solve(√(e/m)=c,e)
```

Edited - it now works (according to my calculator):

```
e = c^2 * m and c >= 0
```

Comment: Looks neat, but would you mind explaining how this arrives at one of the requested solutions?

Comment: CAS = Computer Algebra System. It will solve the given equation (`sqrt(em)=c`) for `e` to give the incorrect equation e=c^2/m.

Comment: @KyleKanos gotcha, thanks. TheDoctor: back to the drawing board, I guess. ;-) Close though.

Comment: @fireeyedboy - oops...

Comment: Not seeing how does it comply with the rules, there aren't 2 expressions, for `m` and for `c`

Answer (score 2):

## Smalltalk, <strike>110</strike> <strike>58</strike> 56

Version 2 below does it, but I guess version1 is interesting enough to not cut it. Read for your amusement (it's about fun here - isn't it)

#### Version 1:

code:

```
(Class name:#S subclassOf:String)compile:'*t^''E='',self,t';compile:'squared^self,''²'''.m:='m'as:S.c:='c'as:S
```

evaluate:

```
m*c squared
```

result:
   'E=mc²'

I really have a hard time to understand what you expect :-(, so I'll give some more detail than usual. Maybe it is of interest to others, even if it does not golf.

First, you want the standard language syntax to be used, eg. in Smalltalk, I would write:

```
m := 100.
c := 299792500.
E := m * c squared.
```

to get "8987554305625000000".

So you want this to be done symbolically. In ST we need a class which redefines the above used operators into string concatenations (any class would do, but I'll inherit from String for convenience, so I get the ,-operator):

```
Class name:#MyString subclassOf:String

    * thingy
        ^ self,thingy asString

    squared
        ^ self,'²'

    = thingy
        ^ self,'=',thingy
```

So now, I can write:

```
m := MyString fromString:'m'.  "/ or 'm' as:MyString for short
c := MyString fromString:'c'.
(m * c squared) print
```

and get 'mc²' as output.

However, and that's my problem: the assignment cannot be redefined,
so saying:

```
E := (m * c squared).
E print
```

would print the same.
In Smalltalk, "=" is a comparison operator (not assignment). "=" was already redefined in the above code. However, as I am calling for a comparison of E against the right side, I need to preset E to something non-nil first:

```
E := MyString fromString:'E'.
```

So let's write:

```
(E = m * c squared) print
```

gives us (the requested?): 'E=mc²'

As you wanted the result of m*c squared, I'll push the 'E' into the multiplication operator:

```
* thingy
    ^ 'E=',self,thingy
```

to fullfill your requirements.

PS: the second comment made it obvious; all I have to change is the assignment in the above class to generate the 'E'.

#### Version 2:

Obviously I was thinking way too complicated:

```
m:=36rEF7U6YC5.c:=7.E:=m*c squared.E digitBytes asString
```

also outputs: 'E=mc^2'

Edit: The large number 1130224008533 is obviously shorter if written in a higher base - hex for example; but it is *much* shorter in base 36, which in Smalltalk is written as 36rEF7U6YC5. This saves me another 2 characters.

PS: how to get to the magic numbers:
`LargeInteger digitBytes:'E=mc^2' asByteArray`
-> 55380976418117
`55380976418117 primeFactors`
-> Bag('4728970747(*1)' '7(*2)' '239(*1)')

Comment: So where's the answer? You need to provide a program, and say how long it is. Then you can explain how and why.

Comment: Basically what I'm looking for is: have two expressions `m` and `c`, for which the result of `m` times `c` squared, when printed as a string, will yield `E=mc²`. Have a look at [squeamish ossifrage's solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21426/7657) in C, for an example.

Comment: that made it clear; I hope I got it right now.

Comment: Sorry, I know next to nothing about Smalltalk to evaluate whether your first solution was too complicated, although I had a strong feeling it was. But your second solution seems to confirm that indeed it was. ;-) That looks a lot more like what I expected to find and what others have come up with as well. Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

## Lua - 74

```
c=rawset(_G,"print",function()io.write"E=mc^2\n"end)and 2 m=2 print(m*c^2)
```

A little cheaty, but not prohibited by the rules:

- Exactly 2 expressions, one for `c`, another for `m`.
- No intermediate variables
- No operator overloading

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL - <s>86 bytes</s> 75 bytes

I'm pretty proud of how competitive this one is for SQL the verbose blabbermouth.

Found myself wishing SQL had a 64-bit binary data type so I could possibly find a bigger square root than 3, but this comes out as a pretty lean one-liner anyway. And it prints the pretty Unicode version! (Which is good, because there were no squares to factor out of the number for E=mc^2)

And it *smokes* the Java entry. ;-)

Jus' kiddin' - @Victor and I are kindred spirits, more interested in playing our best game than winning the prize. Here's to we the crazy ones!

#### New Hotness, 75 bytes

I was hoping for a larger improvement, but due to the vagaries of the query processor I have to explicitly declare @m as a BIGINT or SQL chooses the wrong bit size and the binary result is wrong.  Still, better is better.

```
DECLARE @m BIGINT=33042591394;SELECT CAST(CAST(@m*3*3 AS BINARY(5))AS CHAR)
```

#### Original Submission, 86 bytes

```
DECLARE @c INT=3,@m BIGINT=33042591394;SELECT CAST(CAST(@m*@c*@c AS BINARY(5))AS CHAR)
```

[SQLFiddle Here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15056)

Output:

```
E=mc²
```

Comment: I like it! Nice. :-)

Answer (score 0):

### C# <strike>180 176 171 170</strike> 165

```
using System;namespace N{class P{static void Main(){var m=0x1072699BD55;var c=7;Console.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(m*c*c)));}}}
```

Concept like the Smalltalk version, just for C#.
Output: `E=mc^2`
Use the longer version `var m=0x391DAF9277DEA5D;` for `E=mc²` (actually followed by two spaces)

Edits:
180 to 176: remove 4 spaces
176 to 171: inline usings
171 to 170: Use UTF8 encoding
170 to 165: WriteLine->Write, outline using System; (thanks for the comments)

Comment: PauloHDSousa suggested that you add `using System;` at the beginning and change `System.Console.WriteLine` to `Console.Write` and `System.BitConverter` to `BitConverter`. His suggestion: `using System;namespace N{class P{static void Main(){var m=1130224008533;var c=7;Console.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(m*c*c)));}}}` I think that `System.Text.Encoding` could probably just become `Text.Encoding` (Seems logical). His suggestion saves 6 bytes, but if my idea works, you save 7+6=13 bytes

Comment: Unfortunately `System.Text.Encoding` cannot be shortened as proposed. BTW: how to count bytes reliably? Somehow my count differs by 1.